# Weird animations when editing custom cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, editing

I created a `UITableViewCell` in Xcode 4 using IB. But for some weird reason when I trigger my edit button, the `cell` acts really weird and doesn't have the same animations as a normal table view cell. I don't know what is happening, I tried implementing `-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` in my custom cell class but still nothing works.

**UPDATE:** My `ViewController` that I am using the cell in, has this code under `cellForAtIndex` to display the cell.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) 
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) 
        {
            cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

**Normal view:**

[image: The normal view]

**When tapping edit button:**

[image]

[image: edit]

**And even when swiping it covers the text when it's supposed to move it aside:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suggestion; don't use IB for custom `UITableViewCell`s.

Next; make sure you're adding any custom views to the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`... not just the cell itself. When the editing portions are shown (like the delete button) the `UITableViewCell`'s contentView will shrink automatically. If you have the correct UIViewAutoresizing mask on the `UILabel` / whatever you've added to the `contentView`, it will get resized / moved correctly.

**Edit, to answer your question in comments:**

The same way you would any custom view. You could make it a class on it's own, or, depending on your needs, construct it ad-hoc. A class is usually best so you can reference any of your custom things you've added to the cell and reuse cells / etc.

But, here's is an example of constructing one ad-hoc.

```
UIImageView * myCheckBox = ...
UILabel * myLabel = ...
UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myCheckBox];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
self.customCell = cell;
```

**Edit #2**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, self.contentView.frame.size.width - 50, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: @Ravin455 - I fully understand your problem. I've been there. No need for further explaination.

Comment: if I have to add it programmatically then how should I add it? My only problem is adding the checkbox UIButton on the left side.

Comment: I tried that, just with tableview cell style as `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`. I chose a custom cell in IB instead of adding a `UIImageView`. The only way I can have the functionality of a checkbox is with `UIButton`.

Comment: OK, so use a `UIButton` instead of a `UIImage` view... no different.

Comment: I tried adding a `UIButton` and set the frame to the side, but it just covered the `textLabel`.

Comment: Add your own `UILabel` instead of using the built in one, or make a `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `layoutSubviews` to push the built-in label over.

Comment: so I just create a `NSObject` and make it a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and implement it using `layoutSubviews`, but then how do I push the built-in label over.