# UIButton not working inside UITableView(crashes on tap)? Can I get some help for obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uikit

**SOLUTION**: it was stupidly simple, I overlooked the need to declare the method for my button function in this implementation, the fix was simply adding this in the right spot (inside the implementation... duh!)

```
-(void)bugButton { //do stuff }
```

Found some code for a button that looked like what I wanted. After adding & compiling the button crashes my app when tapped, any idea why? Heres the entire cell, pretty new to making these so its hacked together from other stuff, the button stuff is near the top. I do have the method in a different place (and have used boring PSButtonCell's successfully so I know that the method works)

```
       @interface harpButtonCell : PSTableCell <PreferencesTableCustomView> {

}

@end

@implementation harpButtonCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(id)reuseIdentifier specifier:(id)specifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier specifier:specifier];

    if (self) {
        // icon
        UIImage *bugImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Bug.png", kSelfBundlePath]];
        UIButton *bugbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)];
        [bugbutton setImage:bugImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [bugbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(bugButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:bugbutton];
/*
        UIImage *paypalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Paypal.png", kSelfBundlePath]];
        UIButton *paypalbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)];
        [paypalbutton setImage:paypalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [paypalbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(paypalButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:paypalbutton];*/
//int width = self.contentView.bounds.size.width;
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithSpecifier:(PSSpecifier *)specifier {
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"harpButtonCell" specifier:specifier];
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

- (CGFloat)preferredHeightForWidth:(CGFloat)arg1{
    return 100.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)preferredHeightForWidth:(CGFloat)width inTableView:(id)tableView {
    return [self preferredHeightForWidth:width];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where have you put this code, is it in a UITableViewCell, does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836563/add-button-to-uitableviewcell

Comment: @Flexicoder ah this looks like it does help, if it doesn't work ill edit my q to have the rest of the missing stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't implement the action of button, try to add the action in the cell:

```
-(void)bugButton{
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button");
 }
```

Comment: I do have it in a different place, I know the method is functional as I used to use PSButtonCells, but they take up too much space so I'm trying to get these custom cells instead

Comment: Where do you declare the action for the button?

Comment: OOh! thank you for this question because it helped me realize I need to declare it in my implementation! I was under the impression it would work as long as i had it in there somewhere like the psbuttoncells, thank you very much